# Error: Could not find or load main class when trying to run a java program on command line

Tags: java, cmd

I have the following two java files. When i run it on command line or try to by typing java TwoThreadsTest.java, the error message comes up stating Could not find or load main class TwoThreads.java
I have used the code below to create one java file name nThreadsTest which compiles and gives the output showing the two threads that is 0 figi and 0 jamaica. How do i modify this code to accept input from the command line when being executed. The input will be a non-negative integer number and this number will be used to determine how many threads to execute, E.g. executing java nThreadsTest 5 will execute and start 5 threads.  For each thread called, an integer from 1 to n, (where n is the number passed from the command line), will be passed to the thread as the thread name?

```
class TwoThreadsTest {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        new SimpleThread("Jamaica").start();

        new SimpleThread("Fiji").start();

    }
}

class SimpleThread extends Thread {

    public SimpleThread(String str) {

        super(str);
    }

    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            System.out.println(i + " " + getName());

                for (int j = 1; j < 100000; j++) { // 5 zeroes

                    for (int k = 1; k < 1000000; k++) { // 6 zeroes

                        for (int l = 1; l < 10000000; l++) { // 7 zeroes

                            int m = j + k + l;

                        }                       
                    }
                }

            try {

                sleep((int)(Math.random() * 10000));

                sleep(10000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

        }

        System.out.println("DONE! " + getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the actual command you typed and the full error you received.  (And fix your code formatting while you're editing.)

Answer (score 2):

[image: As seen in here] your code compiles and runs. I think that you try to run it by calling 'java SimpleThread.java'. However, first you need to compile it by calling 'javac' and then run 'java SimpleThread' without the '.java' extension. Hope this helps!

EDIT:

Furthermore if you installed JDK (Java Development Kit), which is necessary to compile java code, you have to setup your environment variables to use 'javac' command directly from the command prompt. The following info is taken directly from the [Oracle's Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html).

> Updating the PATH Environment Variable (Optional)
>   You can run the JDK without setting the PATH environment variable, or you can optionally set it so that you can conveniently run the JDK executable files (javac.exe, java.exe, javadoc.exe, and so forth) from any directory without having to type the full path of the command. If you do not set the PATH variable, you need to specify the full path to the executable file every time you run it, such as:
>
> C:> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\javac" MyClass.java
>   It is useful to set the PATH variable permanently so it will persist after rebooting.
>
> To set the PATH variable permanently, add the full path of the jdk1.7.0\bin directory to the PATH variable. Typically, this full path looks something like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin. Set the PATH variable as follows on Microsoft Windows:
>
> Click Start, then Control Panel, then System.
>
> Click Advanced, then Environment Variables.
>
> Add the location of the bin folder of the JDK installation for the PATH variable in System Variables. The following is a typical value for the PATH variable:
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin
>   Note:
>
> The PATH environment variable is a series of directories separated by semicolons (;) and is not case-sensitive. Microsoft Windows looks for programs in the PATH directories in order, from left to right.
>   You should only have one bin directory for a JDK in the path at a time. Those following the first instance are ignored.
>   If you are not sure where to add the path, add it to the right of the value of the PATH variable.
>   The new path takes effect in each new command window you open after setting the PATH variable.

Comment: Hi furkan, thanks for your quick response, however i am using windows and trying what you said to do by compiling first and typing "javac SimpleThread" and I got an error saying 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: @SusanSummers You don't have Java set up in your system environment variables. Fix that.

Comment: @SusanSummers you can follow this link to setup your environment variables http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html

Comment: Or install Elipse or Netbeans.

Comment: thanks @Unihedron and Furkan, I do have java installed,it's just i wasn't setting the path correctly. It now works.

Comment: Can any one of you help with this now please: How do i modify this code to accept input from the command line when being executed. The input will be a non-negative integer number and this number will be used to determine how many threads to execute, E.g. executing java nThreadsTest 5 will execute and start 5 threads. For each thread called, an integer from 1 to n, (where n is the number passed from the command line), will be passed to the thread as the thread name?

Comment: If the answer worked for you please accept it for future users @SusanSummers I will also give you an example for what you requested if you still need it.

Comment: hi @furkan3ayraktar yes you can still send it to me please.